# Implement a map functional for a list of lists without using nested maps

Tags: functional-programming, f#, sml

I set myself the following challenge (and failed):

I want to write a map functional, `map f lofls`, that takes a function, f `'a -> 'b` and a list of lists, lofls `'a list list` and applies the function `f` on every element of the list of lists. The constraint that I added is that I am not allowed to used nested maps for lists, and I have to do it recursively.

I tried to do it in F# but any language should do. Any ideas?

### Edit

Here is my attempt (which works but is ugly and I am not a fan of the use of rev either . . .)

```
let map f lis = 
    let rec map2 f lis aux =
        match (lis, aux) with
        |([], []) -> []
        |([], aux) -> [aux]
        |(hd::tl, aux) ->
            match hd with 
            |[] -> (List.rev aux) :: (map2 f tl [])
            |x::xs -> map2 f (xs::tl) ( (f x) :: aux )
    map2 f lis []
```

(I also realised that this has been posted in a more concise form  already)

Comment: Do you have any sort of code to show for your failed attempt? Where specifically do you hit a difficulty?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, here is an attempt above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lets go step by step, from simple to complex.

This is the signature that you want your `map` function to have:

`('a -> 'b) -> 'a list list -> 'b list list`

The simple solution is this:

```
let map0 (f:'a -> 'b) (lofls:'a list list) : 'b list list = lofls |> List.map (List.map f)
```

But that one is not recursive and it uses nested maps.

A recursive solution could be this:

```
let rec map1 (f:'a -> 'b) (lofls:'a list list) : 'b list list =
    match lofls with
    | []      -> []
    | l::rest -> (List.map f l) :: map1 f rest
```

It is recursive although it is still calling `List.map` in there.

So, here is the next level:

```
let rec map (f:'a -> 'b) (lofls:'a list list) : 'b list list =
    match  lofls                    with
    | [          ]         -> [              ]
    | [          ] :: rest -> [              ] :: (rest |> map f)
    | ( e::restl ) :: rest -> 
    match  restl   :: rest |> map f with
    | [          ]         -> [              ]
    | [          ] :: rest -> [ f e          ] ::  rest
    | (    restl ) :: rest -> ( f e :: restl ) ::  rest
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly the sort of answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
let rec mapNested f lofls =
    match lofls with
    | []   -> []
    | h::t -> (map f h) :: (mapNested f t)
and map f lst = 
    match lst with
    | []   -> []
    | h::t -> (f h) :: (map f t)
```

Comment: Good answer. Although `map` and `mapNested` do not need to be joined with `and`. Just put `map` first.

Comment: `mapNested f = map (map f)`

Answer (score 2):

If this were a homework question, which I am sure it is not, the answer depends on what constitutes "a nested map for lists".

A construct like `map [] (map [] f)` can be rewritten with pipelining as `f |> map [] |> map []`, or with the function composition operator as `(map [] >> map []) f`, but may be still considered a nested map.

```
let mapNested f =
    let rec map acc g = function
    | [] -> List.rev acc
    | x::xs -> map (g x::acc) g xs
    f |> map [] |> map [] 
// val mapNested : f:('a -> 'b) -> ('a list list -> 'b list list)
```

This is the opportunity to demonstrate your grasp of lambda calculus and the [Y combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Fixed_point_combinators_in_lambda_calculus). Nested passing of the `map` function as an argument should clearly pass muster.

```
let rec Y f x = f (Y f) x

let map f acc g = function
| [] -> List.rev acc
| x::xs -> f (g x::acc) g xs

let map1 f =
    Y map [] f
// val map1 : f:('a -> 'b) -> ('a list -> 'b list)

let map2 f =
    Y map [] f
    |> Y map []
// val map2 : f:('a -> 'b) -> ('a list list -> 'b list list)
```

Answer (score 0):

A tail recursive way

```
let mapNested f lofls =
    let rec map f lst acc =
        match lst with
        | []   -> List.rev acc
        | h::t -> map f t (f h :: acc)
    map (fun x -> map f x []) lofls []
```

Comment: While it will not result in a `StackOverflowException` for large lists, it is still a nested call of `map`, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this question is tagged with SML, but since it is, here is how it can be done in SML:

First, this is the idiomatic solution that you're explicitly avoiding:

```
fun mapmap f = map (map f)
```

*(You could write `val mapmap = map o map` if it weren't for ML's [value restriction](http://mlton.org/ValueRestriction).)*

And if you'd like to write `mapmap` using explicit recursion:

```
fun mapmap f [] = []
  | mapmap f (xs::xss) = map f xs :: mapmap f xss

and map f [] = []
  | map f (x::xs) = f x :: map f xs
```

One reason behind why this function is hard to write with a single explicitly recursive function is that the call stack is used for two things:

1. Collecting the result of each inner list, and
2. Collecting the result of the outer list.

One of those uses of the call stack can be turned into an explicit stack in an accumulating argument. This is how e.g. a tail-recursive `rev` is defined:

```
fun rev xs =
  let fun aux [] acc = acc
        | aux (x::xs) acc = aux xs (x::acc)
  in aux xs [] end
```

The accumulating argument similarly isn't needed in the interface to `mapmap`, so it can be hidden in an inner helper function. So a single function that performs explicit recursion on both the inner and the outer list is complicated by this explicit bookkeeping:

```
fun mapmap f xss =
  let fun aux f [] _ = []
        | aux f ([]::xss) ys = rev ys :: aux f xss []
        | aux f ((x::xs)::xss) ys = aux f (xs::xss) (f x :: ys)
  in aux f xss [] end
```